# Asynchrony problem trying to recursively call an API

Tags: javascript, api, loops, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to build a dictionary based on the API calls that I have to do, giving to the API a given id for each call. After this process, I need to operate on the generated dictionary. The problem is that I cannot get the asynchrony to work properly.

I have tried to implement Promises with no success.

```
var self = this;


    function fillPropertyDict(){
        var itemsProcessed = 0;
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {

            //Loop for every ID
            self._bimIds.forEach((bimId) => {
                itemsProcessed++;

                //Calling the API
                self.viewer.model.getProperties(bimId, (resultado) => {
                    resultado.properties.forEach((prop) => {
                        if(prop.displayName == 'Type' && prop.displayCategory == 'BIM 360') {
                            var foundIndex = self._propertyDictionary.findIndex(x => x.dbId == bimId)
                            if (foundIndex > 0){
                                self._propertyDictionary[foundIndex].equipment = prop.displayValue
                            } else {
                                var el = new Object();
                                el.dbId = bimId;
                                el.equipment = prop.displayValue;
                                el.sap = '';
                                self._propertyDictionary.push(el);
                            }

                        } else if (prop.displayName == 'Description' && prop.displayCategory == 'BIM 360') {
                            var foundIndex = self._propertyDictionary.findIndex(x => x.dbId == bimId)
                            if (foundIndex > 0){
                                self._propertyDictionary[foundIndex].sap = prop.displayValue
                            } else {
                                var el = new Object();
                                el.dbId = bimId;
                                el.equipment = '';
                                el.sap = prop.displayValue;
                                self._propertyDictionary.push(el);
                            }

                        }
                    })

                })
            //If count reaches array length, resolve Promise
            if(itemsProcessed == self._bimIds.length){
                //Resolve inside callback
                resolve(self._propertyDictionary);
            }

            })
        });   
    }




    //Call function
    fillPropertyDict().
    then(function(result) {
        //Let's print the dictionary  
        console.log('Lets see self._propertyDictionary'); 
        console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) );  
        console.log(result);   

}
```

I would like the see the actual dictionary when I call the function containing the promise (fillPropertyDict()).

Comment: Which part is not working?

Comment: When I console.log( JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)) ) in the calling function, I get no result, and if I check the dictionary length, I get 0.

Comment: Yeah but have you tried debugging?